# href="tel:xxxxxxxx" not working on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, href

```
      <a
          href="tel:+xxxxxxxxxx"
        >CALL 6514 9729
      </a>
```

this code is printing this error on mobile view !

[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

Answer (score 0):

it was a CSS issue ! apparently only position relative could make the call work on mobile view. not sure why though!